# How can I make a horizontal ellipse appear to go through a vertical one?

Tags: inkscape, appearance

How can I make the horizontal ellipse (in the image on the left) appear to go through the vertical one as shown in the image on the right?

[image: inkscape vector ptts]

I want the horizontal circle to look like it goes through the vertical one. How can I make it appear so by manipulating the path (like exclude or intersection)?

Comment: See also the **[knot](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-Knot.html) path effect**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes a simplified example, with 2 ellipses.

Draw your 2 ellipses, select them and convert to path (*Path->Stroke to path*, maybe this is not strictly necessary).

[image: 2 ellipses]

Then get the horizontal (blue) ellipse, duplicate it (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>), and offset a couple of times (<kbd>Ctrl-(</kbd>).

[image: Duplicate and offset]

Now, draw a rectangle over the area you want to alter:

[image: Rectangle over area of interest]

Select the offset (thick) ellipse and the rectangle, and intersect both (*Path->Intersection*).

[image]

Now you want to remove this thick section from your red ellipse. Select the red ellipse and then the thick blue section, and get the difference (*Path->Difference*), to get the following:

[image: Final result]

Now, you can repeat the procedure for the other crossing.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

[image]

- Don't use a closed ellipse shape, but just a part of it, as selectable with the ellipse tool.
- Transform the outline to a path in the path menue.
- Then add a white border atound it. Have an eye on the size of the border (don't do it like I did). Half of the border will overlap the inner part of the shape, so you have to add that part upfront.